# Big Database Size - What happen to phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
Mysql said #2006 - MySQL server has gone away
```

In php.ini I have this:

```
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M
```

I also put this line in config.inc.php

```
$cfg ['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

The database size that I want to upload is 237MB

How could this happen?

Thanks.

Comment: what is your `max_allowed_packet`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet

Comment: @bansi max_allowed_packet = 10M . Any idea?

Comment: and you are trying to upload a 237MB query?

Comment: @bansi sure. You mean 10M doesn't enough to upload 237MB ? NO.

Comment: if you are trying to upload the entire database as a single query (phpMyAdmin does this when you upload file as query) your query size must be less than `max_allowed_packet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be due to improper setting of variable  **'max_allowed_packet'**

Increase this variable in My.cnf or my.ini file of MySQL server .
set  max_allowed_packet = 1 M

Hope it works!!

Comment: There is no ideal amount of this...
This represent size of a single query data

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is most likely the mysql's setting [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) and/or [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet).
You can see the values for these settings using [SHOW VARIABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-variables.html).

If you are able, use the utility [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) to export/import your tables. 
In short, using command line:

```
mysqldump -u -pPASS -h HOST_SOURCE database > dump.sql 
mysql -u -pPASS -h HOST_DESTINATION -D otherdatabase < dump.sql
```